Cargo failed to load source dependency, virtual manifest
I'm new to Rust/Cargo and been struggling to address an issue when compiling a new Yocto recipe for gst-plugins-rs, the Cargo.toml file can be found in this directory structure.
../gstreamer1.0-plugins-rs/0.12.11-r0/git/
├── audio
│   ├── audiofx
│   ├── claxon
│   ├── csound
│   ├── lewton
│   └── spotify
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.lock.orig
├── Cargo.toml
├── cargo_wrapper.py
├── CHANGELOG.md
|   ...
└── video
    ├── cdg
    ...
    └── webp

The Cargo.toml basically consists of the following.
[workspace]
resolver = "2"

members = [
  "audio/audiofx"
  "audio/claxon"
  ...
]

default-members = [
  "audio/audiofx"
  "audio/claxon"
  ...
]

[workspace.package]
version = "0.12.11"
repository = "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs"
edition = "2021"
rust-version = "1.70"

[workspace.dependencies]
once_cell = "1"
glib = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core", branch = "0.19", version = "0.19" }
...
gtk = { package = "gtk4", git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs", branch = "0.8", version = "0.8"}
...
gst = { package = "gstreamer", git = "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs", branch = "0.22", version = "0.22" }
...

Regarding the Yocto Recipe there's not much out of the ordinary, only a custom do_install that moves .so files, but it's failing in the do_compile stage.  The recipe is based off this old patch request, but has been updated to more recent versions. Basically consisting of the following,
...
SRC_URI = " \
    git://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs.git;protocol=https;branch=0.12;name=default; \
    gitsm://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs.git;protocol=https;branch=0.22;name=gstreamer-rs;destsuffix=cargo_home/git/db/gstreamer-rs-79e52a2d27eb91a3 \
    git://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core.git;protocol=https;branch=0.19;name=gtk-rs-core;destsuffix=cargo_home/git/db/gtk-rs-core-7be42ca38bd6361c \
    git://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs;protocol=https;branch=0.8;name=gtk4-rs;destsuffix=cargo_home/git/db/gtk4-rs-e74ad56283dfeb5e \
    git://github.com/rust-av/ffv1.git;protocol=https;branch=master;name=ffv1;destsuffix=cargo_home/git/db/ffv1-08f2e3b26709fb34 \
    git://github.com/rust-av/flavors;protocol=https;branch=master;name=flavors;destsuffix=cargo_home/git/db/flavors-0f978a4d88ad8592 \
    crate://crates.io/adler/1.0.2 \
    crate://crates.io/adler32/1.2.0 \
    crate://crates.io/aes/0.8.4 \
    crate://crates.io/aho-corasick/1.1.3 \
    ...

inherit cargo pkgconfig

DEPENDS = " \
    gstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
"
...

The error I'm receiving is the following,
cargo build -v --frozen --target aarch64-lmp-linux-gnu --release --manifest-path=.../gstreamer1.0-plugins-rs/0.12.11-r0/git//Cargo.toml
NOTE: cargo build -v --frozen --target aarch64-lmp-linux-gnu --release --manifest-path=.../gstreamer1.0-plugins-rs/0.12.11-r0/git//Cargo.toml 
error: failed to load source for dependency `gtk4-rs`

Caused by:
  Unable to update .../gstreamer1.0-plugins-rs/0.12.11-r0/cargo_home/git/db/gtk4-rs-e74ad56283dfeb5e

Caused by:
  found a virtual manifest at `.../gstreamer1.0-plugins-rs/0.12.11-r0/cargo_home/git/db/gtk4-rs-e74ad56283dfeb5e/Cargo.toml` instead of a package manifest

Perhaps I need to convert gtk4-rs's Cargo.toml to a package manifest? Or is there a cargo command that needs to be changed so that it expects a virtual manifest?
Any suggestions would be much appreciated and I'm happy to share more details. Also if there are some cargo debugging commands I could run, please let me know.
I initially thought the SRC_URI, specifically the destsuffix, was the issue initially, but when removing the sources, e.g. gstreamer-rs, gtk-rs-core, etc, I've confirmed that gst-plugins-rs is looking for those other sources at those paths.

I’m not familiar with Yocto, so I can’t advise you on exactly how to fix this problem, but I am familiar with Cargo. Based on the build error, you seem to be trying to replace git dependencies with path dependencies.
Cargo has a special behavior for Git dependencies, that no other dependency type has: it will search the contents of (the requested revision of) the repository for the requested package (here gtk4). So, when Cargo looks at https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs, it searches until it finds the package manifest https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/blob/main/gtk4/Cargo.toml, not the workspace manifest https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/blob/main/Cargo.toml. (I believe the workspace manifest does not at all affect the search, but I could be wrong.)
path dependencies have no such search behavior — the path must be to the
directory containing exactly the needed package manifest. So, when you wish to transform a git dependency to a path dependency, you must find the correct package directory within the repository and use that path in the dependency.
The reason Cargo says “found a virtual manifest” is that a virtual manifest is a manifest that does not define a package, only a workspace. For your purposes, understand the error as “no package found in this directory, but FYI, we did find something else that is not a package”. You need to point Cargo to the correct (sub)directory instead.

Thanks so much Kevin!  Gives me something to investigate further today, may have follow on questions.

Appreciate the help Kevin, using "path" instead of "git" got me past that issue.  I was wondering if I could pick your brain on my next issue?

@kengineer When you post another Rust question, I'll see it.
